# Making custom XML file in Liferay

Tags: php, xml, liferay, velocity

Is it possible to make a custom `XML` file in Liferay either with `PHP`, `VM` or anything else?

I have a default page, with a `form` and `text fields`. When i fill out the `form` and press the "finish" `button` below, i want it to create a XML file with the details i just filled in the `form`. After that the XML file should be send to a `FTP` where it is stored.

I have the `XML` file as it should be, as a `template`, but outside Liferay.

Example for the `XML` content:

```
<CustomizedFields>
        <CustomizedField>
            <Name>VIP Customer</Name>
            <Type>Boolean</Type>
            <Value>True</Value>
            <UnitOfMeasure>Kg</UnitOfMeasure>
        </CustomizedField>
</CustomizedFields>
```

How can i do this? Is there a `hook`'er already make or is it even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my knowledge of Liferay, I recommend reading up on the attached link. It sounds like you require customization of the software's core struts classes. Expose the data conduit by using Portal Hook Plugins, further attached. This will enable you to use custom XML in a Liferay portlet.

[Creating an EXT Plugin in Liferay](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-an-ext-plug-4)

[XML Customization in Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portal+Hook+Plugins)

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot :-) I'll try look at it

Comment: EXT and Hook! not required in this scenario. And moreover the question is not clear enough like how the form is being shown?

Comment: I suppose that I am suggesting to integrate the feature in Java. But am I right in assuming that this could be solved using an EXT and hook?

Comment: I don't understand which default behaviour you'd like to override (which would call for ext or hook). Thus I'm rather suggesting a portlet. Now if you'd care to describe what functionality you had in mind to override, this opinion might change, so far I can't see any. Unrelated: Liferay does not have any capital "R".

Comment: Olaf, I am new to Liferay development, and believe that your method makes more sense. I believe that the method I am suggesting would be to override the default functionality with new functionality that is yet undefined to accomplish the same goal. I can't delete an "Accepted" answer, so... This is what happens when I stay up very late trying to answer questions.

Comment: Hi Tyler, thanks for the clarification and welcome to Liferay.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know where you want to display your form, but it looks like you can get along with a simple portlet that just displays the form and saves the parameters in any format you like. I don't see anything specific that you should do to customize Liferay (other than adding another portlet), neither with ext, nor with a hook.

Why you choose a Java platform (Liferay) and then attempt to solve the problem in PHP is beyond me - however, a while ago I've even seen a sample-php portlet. I'd not go that route though. In case there's anything not working, only few people will be able to help you. And you don't sound like you have too much experience in the portal world - so stick with the easiest and best documented way: [Write a portlet](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/developing-portlet-applications-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-03--2)